# Correctly call a JSON function

Tags: javascript, json

How can I call the `loadlist` function correctly when I have this JSON data?

I am calling like this but it’s not working:

```
loadlist($('select#selName').get(0), 'pull.php','data.name')
```

Here is my JSON data:

```
{
  data: [
    {
      id: "e0b0d8sc5ffd82e",
      name: "John",
    }
  ]
}
```

the function

```
function loadlist(selobj,url,nameattr) {
  $(selobj).empty();
  $.getJSON(url,{},function(data)
  {
    $(selobj).append(
        $('<option>Select</option>')
                    .val('null')
    );

    $.each(data, function(i,obj)
    {
        $(selobj).append(
             $('<option></option>')
                    .val(obj[nameattr])
                    .html(obj[nameattr]));
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Are you calling it exactly like that? Aren't you missing a `'` after `'pull.php`?

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean?

Comment: No, you cannot use bracket notation like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumption that `obj["data.name"]` is equal to `obj.data.name` is wrong. (The equivalent requires two property accesses: `obj["data"]["name"]`)

If you think you might need to do nested property retrievals, you might have better luck passing in a function for retrieving the property. (This also will work if you need to use a dynamically computed value.)

```
function loadlist(selobj,url,getter) {
  $(selobj).empty();
  $.getJSON(url,{},function(data)
  {
    $(selobj).append(
        $('<option>Select</option>')
                    .val('null')
    );

    $.each(data, function(i,obj)
    {
        var value = getter(obj);
        $(selobj).append(
             $('<option></option>')
                    .val(value)
                    .html(value));
    });
  });
}

// Call as follows:
loadlist($('select#selName').get(0), 'pull.php', function (obj) {
    return obj.data.name;
});
```

Comment: I am trying to work with your sample code but I still don't get the drop down filled.. what else could it be?

Comment: here's the error I get http://screencast.com/t/oYbnDRWCrc5

Comment: Can you please post your updated code?

Comment: my updated code is exactly what you posted, I did copy/paste..